# Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) SDK bulk insert optimization and performance

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

There are two SQL tables without FK but have one common property which I use to join them into a list where I get 1 300 000 records. That column(property) is not unique inside both tables (can occur more than once). I need to insert those 1 300 000 records from that joined memory list inside Azure Cosmos DB using v3 SDK and using a bulk insert for that purpose.
Problem is that this bulk insert lasts for more than 10-15 minutes even though I have set the throughput 50 000 or 100 000. I have tried few approaches and none of them gave me better results. The only time when I got it working was when I joined both tables with LINQ into the parent-children list then I got around 2900 documents and bulk insert was around 33 seconds but then the size of the documents even though I optimized JSON serialization (shortening strings, dates, ignoring null values, etc.) was for some cases more than 2MB.
When inserting 1 300 000 documents with a throughput of 100 000(testing) I also get Service Unavailable or TooManyRequest exceptions.
I am using an emulator and I am new to azure cosmos.

Creating Singleton instance:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(x =>
        {
            var primaryConnectionString = _solutionConfiguration.AzureCosmosDb.PrimaryConnectionString;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(primaryConnectionString))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Please specify a valid CosmosDBConnection in the solutionsettings.json file or your Azure Functions Settings.");
            }

            return new CosmosClientBuilder(primaryConnectionString)
            .WithSerializerOptions(new CosmosSerializationOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase, IgnoreNullValues = true })
            .WithRequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))
            .WithBulkExecution(true).Build();
        });
```

Container creation:

```
public async static Task CreatContainerForDatabase(CosmosClient cosmosClient, string databaseId, string containerId, string partitionKey)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">>>>> Create New Container >>>>>");

        var containerProperties = new ContainerProperties
        {
            Id = containerId,
            PartitionKeyPath = partitionKey
        };

        var result = await cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseId).CreateContainerAsync(containerProperties, 150000);


        Console.WriteLine($"New container with id: {result.Container.Id} has been created");
    }
```

Insert to Cosmos db

```
 Console.WriteLine("Bulk insert!");

        var cost = 0D;
        var errors = 0;

        var documentsToCreate = boatsWithPricesFirstYear.Count();

        var executionStarted = DateTime.Now;
        var container = _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_configuration.AzureCosmosDb.DatabaseId, _configuration.AzureCosmosDb.ContainerId);

        var tasks = new List<Task>(documentsToCreate);

        foreach (var boat in boatsWithPricesFirstYear)
        {

            var result = container.CreateItemAsync(boat, new PartitionKey(boat.BoatId));

            tasks.Add(result.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    cost += t.Result.RequestCharge;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error creating boat with id: {boat.BoatId} document: {t.Exception.Message}");
                    errors++;
                }
            }));

        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine($"{documentsToCreate - errors} documents has been created at cost of: {cost:0.##} RUs in {DateTime.Now.Subtract(executionStarted)}");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Also when I console log Request charge (RU/s) I get around 9 million RU/s for all (1 300 000) documents is there any way to reduce this charge when inserting items (I am aware that SQL API for writing purposes takes around 10.2 RU/s for one item if I am right).
When I make this list which I am trying to insert in cosmos as a parent-children list (boat->parent, prices for every day->children) I get around 2900 documents with a request charge of 850 000 RU/s.

I have tried Microsoft example as well with stream https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-sql-api-dotnet-bulk-import but I got almost the same results.

If I lack some information I will update this post. Thanks in advance.

P.S. My local memory is also dying when bulk insert is in process.

Comment: The Emulator is not a reflection of how the real service will behave in terms of processing power, and if you are running the Emulator in the same machine, you are sharing the machine resources between all your processes. When running Bulk mode in a dev environment, you are not really measuring the real processing speed (your machine is not in Azure so you have network latency, you are running other processes that take away CPU, etc). Have you tried running it on a machine in the cloud co-located (same region) as your Cosmos DB account?

Comment: Thank you Matias for answer. I am using emulator just for testing purposes, I did not want to test it on cloud because  i can not calculate how much RU/s will I spend and how much money that will cost. Writing is expensive and when I calculate RU/s through application I get 850 000 - 9 000 000 depends if there are 2500 documents or 1 300 000 documents. ( depends  on object structure)

Comment: Makes sense. There are two things important when measuring: Emulator will never map to the real scenario, as your PC does not equal the Azure machines in terms of performance, and if you run any measurement, make sure you are running on Release build, not in a Debug build / inside VS. Bulk won't reduce RU consumption, it will just remove the client-side network bottle neck. If you create 1 document and costs X RU, and you have Y provisioned, then your per second insert rate would be Y / X documents, anything higher would get throttled. You can always increase the Retry count for throttles

Comment: I understand now, thank you a lot.